# How does Android's proximity sensor work?

Tags: android

I'm reading the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-prox) and I see this

> The proximity sensor lets you determine how far away an object is from a device. The following code shows you how to get an instance of the default proximity sensor
>
> The proximity sensor is usually used to determine how far away a person's head is from the face of a handset device (for example, when a user is making or receiving a phone call). Most proximity sensors return the absolute distance, in cm, but some return only near and far values. The following code shows you how to use the proximity sensor:

Key statements being "usually used" and the general use of the term "object".

Can I specify that the object should be an apple on a tree in front of me? This documentation doesn't really give me any idea how the proximity position sensor works. Or is the sensor a chip inserted on an external object that android can pick up?

Comment: Considering they give an absolute distance, it seems clear the device will send out a signal of some type and use the time for the signal to reflect back and the speed of the signal to determine that distance. I think the API neglects an explanation because the sensors are hardware based.

Comment: So the number that I get is based on arbitrarily anything, and so it is useful only when there is context (eg: when you put your phone near your ear and you assume that the number returned is the distance from device to ear...)

Comment: Seems so, you may have experienced a media player that automatically pauses or goes silent when the screen is placed face down on a table. I doubt Android can readily determine *what* the object is. You could always set up a simple app that tests the functionality against different objects, orientation, and positions.

Answer (score 1):

I expect it just emits an IR beam and measures how much light bounces back. See http://thecodeartist.blogspot.com/2011/01/proximity-sensor-on-android-gingerbread.html?m=1